# Moving Sprite in direction it is rotated (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'am making a space shooter in Unity. The problem is that I can't get the sprite to move in the direction it is rotated. How can I do it?

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float speed = 13f;
  public Animator animator;
  public Rigidbody2D rigidBody2D;
  public float rotation = 0.0f;

void Start()
{
    rigidBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
     if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){  
        Vector2 pos = rigidBody2D.velocity;
        pos.y += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        rigidBody2D.velocity = pos;
    } 

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
        rigidBody2D.SetRotation(rotation);
        rotation += 2.0f;
    }
      if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
        rigidBody2D.SetRotation(rotation);
        rotation -= 2.0f;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can get the facing(or forward) direction by multiplying the orientation by whatever axis you use for rotating your game object.

Below are three examples:

```
// Top down example: the spaceship rotate in it's Y axis
// first, let's get its facing direction
Vector3 forwardDirection = spaceshipObject.transform.rotation * Vector3.up;

// then we can move the spaceship forward
// either with normal Transform
Vector3 moveDirection = forwardDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime;
spaceshipObject.transform.position += moveDirection;
// if you dont want to do the maths, you can directly use Unity's builtin transform.forward to move your ship, it does the same as line 3
Vector3 moveDirection = spaceshipObject.transform.forward;
spaceshipObject.transform.Translate(moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
// Or if you fancy using Rigibodies
rigidbody.velocity = forwardDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```